When parent height isn't fixed and alignItems is set to center, I can't get child height to fill parent height
Here's the code I'm working with:


.App {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

.item2 {
 height: 5rem;
}
<div class="App">
    <div class="item item1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="item item2">Div 2</div>
 </div>



And the result looks like the following:

How can I get Div1 height to fill parent height (or to match height of Div2) without touching the css of the parent?
Note that I do not have access to the parent component, so can't modify its css. Also note that though Div2 height is fixed in this example, in reality it changes dynamically, and I want Div1 to adjust its height dynamically whenever Div2's height changes.

I assume the height of the parent is determined by the height of div 2?

Give the required child align-self: stretch;


.parent {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .25em;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-self: stretch;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  align-self: stretch;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  height: 5rem;
}
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
</div>



